# How to Reduce 3G data consumption using Google Map API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an android application that requires to display the current location of a user and to load KMZ file (with poly lines) on Google Map (use of google map api).

My application opens the google map, loads the KMZ file and diplays current position fast, when having wi-fi and 3G enabled to mobile.The problem I face is that having 3G the data consumption is too big. I checked that after 5 clicks/zoom in-out on a single map the data consumption on mobile become 100MB..

Are there any ways to reduce the 3G data consumption? Should I use another map source?

Thanks

Comment: Fix map on specific zoom level.

Comment: An example KMZ file?

Comment: KMZ file has size of 2,5 MB.